# How to skip ahead a certain number with .next()

Tags: python

I have a for loop and some if statements in which I'm trying to print out some data like so:

```
for i in range(27):
    if (i >= 0) and (i <= 11):
        print "   value %d = %02X" % (i, data.next())
    if (i >= 16) and (i <= 27):
        print "   value %d = %02X" % (i, data.next())
```

So, the first 12 values print out fine, but then when i = 16 through 27, the value of i prints out correctly, but the data.next()) part does not. It's not keeping up with i I'm pretty sure. Is there a way to keep the .next() on pace with the value of i?

Comment: Why not just read and discard `next()` if neither condition holds?

Comment: Also, not related to what you're asking, but you could do `0 <= i <= 11` instead of `(i >= 0) and (i <= 11)`

Comment: Yup! Been awhile since I programmed in python, I'm still trying to figure out what I can and can't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alexis stated, you could just add an else clause and call data.next() in it. Code is probably easier to understand than my explanation.

```
for i in range(27):
    if (i >= 0) and (i <= 11):
        print "   value %d = %02X" % (i, data.next())
    elif (i >= 16) and (i <= 27):
        print "   value %d = %02X" % (i, data.next())
    else:
        data.next()
```

Or since the two clauses do the same thing you could test for when i > 11 and i < 16.

```
for i in range(27):
    if (i > 11) and (i < 16):
        data.next() # keeps data moving forward even when i == 12, 13, 14, 15
    else:
        print "   value %d = %02X" % (i, data.next()) # only prints when i == 0...11, 16...27
```

Comment: Good call. Easy solution, I should have thought of that. Thank you!